# How do I get to root on pfSense?

Tags: sudo, pfsense, sudoers

I am running pfSense `21.05.2` in AWS.  I can ssh in as `ec2-user`, and I can see that the `sudo` package (`0.3_6` with a dependency on `sudo-1.9.7`) came pre-installed.  In the web interface, under `System` > `Sudo`, I can see the `ec2-user` has `Run As` privileges for `root` and `No Password` is checked and the `Command List` is `ALL`.

This is the behavior I observe in the shell:

```
> whoami
ec2-user

> sudo su -
su: Sorry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo su - admin` will let you become `root`.

In AWS pfSense `21.05.2`, you login with the **username** `admin` and automatically are `root` after choosing option 8:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_key.pem admin@<your_ip>

*** Welcome to Netgate pfSense Plus 21.05.2-RELEASE (amd64) on pfsense ***

 WAN (wan)       -> ena0       -> v4/DHCP4: <your_ip>/<bits>

 0) Logout (SSH only)                  9) pfTop
 1) Assign Interfaces                 10) Filter Logs
 2) Set interface(s) IP address       11) Restart webConfigurator
 3) Reset webConfigurator password    12) PHP shell + Netgate pfSense Plus tools
 4) Reset to factory defaults         13) Update from console
 5) Reboot system                     14) Disable Secure Shell (sshd)
 6) Halt system                       15) Restore recent configuration
 7) Ping host                         16) Restart PHP-FPM
 8) Shell

Enter an option: 8

> whoami
root

> cat /usr/local/etc/sudoers
root ALL=(root)  ALL
admin ALL=(root)  ALL
%admins ALL=(root)  ALL
ec2-user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

You will see that `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` contains the same key as as `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` (the key you specified when you launched the instance).

If you try to login as `root@<your_ip>`, you will get a `Permission denied (publickey).` error.

The reason `sudo su -` does not work by itself is that without a username specified, `root` is implied, and you cannot login to `root` directly (but must go through the `admin` menu).